#  How can I create a method which accesses a variable from a dynamic class name?

Tags: java, object, dynamic

I have an "Extension" class for handling general functions that's designed to be used dynamically - that is, I want to be able to use it with many different classes and variables (kind of like how you would use something like the Math class). But I've encountered a little problem that I can't seem to figure out (I've looked at quite a few forums and websites, but no luck).

Here's the function from my Extension class:

```
public void setPlayerFriction(Object objectType, double hspeed, double vspeed){
    objectType obj = new objectType();

    if(obj.hspeed >= GameWindow.friction){
          obj.hspeed -= GameWindow.friction;
    }else if(obj.hspeed <= -GameWindow.friction){
          obj.hspeed += GameWindow.friction;
    }else{
          obj.hspeed = 0;
    }
    if(obj.vspeed >= GameWindow.friction){
          obj.vspeed -= GameWindow.friction;
    }else if(obj.vspeed <= -GameWindow.friction){
          obj.vspeed += GameWindow.friction;
    }else{
          obj.vspeed = 0;
    }
}
```

And the function's use in my Player class:

```
public void runPhysicsEngine(){
    Extensions ext = new Extensions();
    ext.setPlayerFriction(this,hspeed,vspeed);
}
```

Obviously doing something like `obj.var -= GameWindow.friction;`, where `obj` and `var` are arguments of a method, isn't the right way to do what I want to do - it just returns the unresolved type error. So what is the right way? How do I access a variable from a dynamic class name?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using. In general, what you're doing requires using the language's introspection mechanism, and may not even be possible in some languages.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I totally forgot about tagging the language name. Whoops! And as for your suggestion: I'm not familiar with introspection mechanisms. Could you link me to an article explaining them? And you could you tell me if Java has one?

Comment: Google "java introspection" and you'll find lots of information. Here's an article that was linked to from another SO answer: http://java.sys-con.com/node/35980

Comment: Just use a common interface for the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having an `abstract` class for your `objectType` with appropriate `getter/setter` methods might help. For example:

```
public abstract class ParentObject {

    private double hSpeed;
    private double vSpeed;

    /** Getter/setter methods */

    public double gethSpeed() {
        return hSpeed;
    }
    public void sethSpeed(double hSpeed) {
        this.hSpeed = hSpeed;
    }
    public double getvSpeed() {
        return vSpeed;
    }
    public void setvSpeed(double vSpeed) {
        this.vSpeed = vSpeed;
    }
}
```

You can then have concrete implementation of your `ObjectType` classes that `extend` this `ParentObject` class. And you would change your `setPlayerFriction()` method as follows:

```
public void setPlayerFriction(ParentObject objectType, double hspeed, double vspeed){

    double hSpeed = objectType.gethSpeed();
    if(hSpeed >= GameWindow.friction){
          objectType.sethSpeed(hSpeed - GameWindow.friction);
    }else if(hSpeed <= -GameWindow.friction){
          objectType.sethSpeed(hSpeed + GameWindow.friction);
    }else{
          objectType.sethSpeed(0);
    }

    double vSpeed = getvSpeed();
    if(vSpeed >= GameWindow.friction){
          objectType.setvSpeed(vSpeed - GameWindow.friction);
    }else if(obj.vspeed <= -GameWindow.friction){
          objectType.setvSpeed(vSpeed + GameWindow.friction);
    }else{
          objectType.setvSpeed(0);
    }
}
```

And to this method, you would basically be sending references of classes that have actually extended your `ParentObject` class. For example:

```
public class ObjImpl extends ParentObject{
    //Concrete implementation
}

public class ObjImpl2 extends ParentObject{
    //Concrete implementation
}

public class TestClass{
    public void setPlayerFriction(ParentObject objectType, double hspeed, double vspeed){   
        double hSpeed = objectType.gethSpeed();
        if(hSpeed >= GameWindow.friction){
              objectType.sethSpeed(hSpeed - GameWindow.friction);
        }else if(hSpeed <= -GameWindow.friction){
              objectType.sethSpeed(hSpeed + GameWindow.friction);
        }else{
              objectType.sethSpeed(0);
        }

        double vSpeed = getvSpeed();
        if(vSpeed >= GameWindow.friction){
              objectType.setvSpeed(vSpeed - GameWindow.friction);
        }else if(obj.vspeed <= -GameWindow.friction){
              objectType.setvSpeed(vSpeed + GameWindow.friction);
        }else{
              objectType.setvSpeed(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParentObject object1    = new ObjImpl();
        ParentObject object2    = new ObjImpl2();

        setPlayerFriction(object1, 1.0d, 2.0d);
        setPlayerFriction(object2, 2.25d, 2.0d);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! :D
I'm going to test it to make sure it works before I accept it, but if it's really what I need, thank you very much :)

One thing: is it really necessary to have a parent object? It seems a bit inefficient to me. Hm... I'll experiment around.

Comment: @Vaysym: Well it would depend on your requirement. I just gave it as an example so yeah, tweak it to suit your need. If it works for you, do accept and up-vote if you like :)

Comment: Sounds good :) I just tested out your paradigm, and one problem I'm having is making the Parent class's variables somehow affect the Player class's variables... or use it to get through to the Player. When I do anything like `objectType.sethSpeed(5);` in my `Extensions.setFriction()` method, it only changes the variables in the Parent class (yes, I've extended Parent to the Player class). What's going on? o.o

Comment: @Vaysym: Are you making sure that you're not `re-defining` the same variables in the `Player` class? Also an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) version of your code might help us all to better understand your current implementation and the issue

Comment: Whoops, I did exactly that... Haha. By also changing the variable types in the Parent class to `protected` the program now seems to be running well. Except, if I create a Player2 class, the hSpeed and vSpeed seem to be shared with the Player class... Do I need to create a Parent object for each Player object? Or are the variables being mixed up because of the `protected` modifier?

Comment: @Vaysym: You're mixing something up, but I can't hazard a guess about that :) If you've two separate `Player` objects, then they would be behaving separately for sure.

Comment: I played with it for a bit, and it seems to be working well now :)
However, this method is a bit long and ridiculous for what I would be using it for, so I think that I'll just do without my Extensions class and do everything in the Player classes anyway, but I'll definitely keep this saved for future use. Thank you for helping me out! :)